# Query for material-ui input by label in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am attempting to write a test case to assert that a number input is disabled while a radio option is selected and am having trouble using React Testing Library utils to query for the HTML `<input>` rendered by a Material UI `<TextField>`.

There are two `<TextField>` instances in the component that this test applies to, so I am attempting to use the `findAllByLabelText` query and then loop through those nodes to confirm the disabled state.

##### React Component

```
function OverridePriceModal () {
  ...
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <TextField
        type="number"
        label="Custom Pricing"
        value={regularPriceOverride}
        onChange={evt => setRegularPriceOverride(evt.target.value)}
        disabled={!isRegularPriceOverridden}
      />
      ...
      <TextField
        type="number"
        label="Custom Pricing"
        value={specialPriceOverride}
        onChange={evt => setSpecialPriceOverride(evt.target.value)}
        disabled={!isSpecialPriceOverridden}
      />
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

##### Unit Test

```
test('custom price inputs are disabled while following system pricing', async () => {
  render(<OverridePriceModal />);

  const priceInputs = await screen.findAllByLabelText('Custom Pricing');
  _.forEach(priceInputs, input => {
    expect(input).toBeDisabled();
  });
});
```

##### Expected Results

I expect the input node to be found by label text, and to be disabled, leading to a passing test.

##### Actual Results

I receive the following error message in test output:

> Found a label with the text of: Custom Pricing, however no form control was found associated to that label. Make sure you're using the "for" attribute or "aria-labelledby" attribute correctly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, apparently all I had to do was use stack overflow as a rubber duck, because I immediately figured it out..

##### Solution

Simply add `id` prop to `<TextField>`.

The `label` and `input` within the MUI `TextField` are not properly linked with the `for` attribute unless you provide the `id` prop, as noted under the **Accessibility** section of the [MUI TextField docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#accessibility).

Maybe unit tests will force best practices on me after all..

Comment: Any idea how to make this work within a reused component? I've tried using inputRef but to no avail...